# Problem using KeychainItemWrapper

Tags: iphone, keychain

I use the following code to retrieve the login credentials from the iPhone keychain:

```
KeychainItemWrapper *wrapper = [[KeychainItemWrapper alloc] initWithIdentifier:@"Test" accessGroup:nil];
NSString *username = [wrapper objectForKey:(id)kSecAttrAccount];
NSString *password = [wrapper objectForKey:(id)kSecValueData];
[wrapper release];
```

I'm under the impression that the first time a user launches the app, neither username nor password could be retrieved from the keychain, so `username` and `password` should be equal to `nil`. I, however, was unable to print out any of these variables using `NSLog`.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What were you able to print? Why don't you set a breakpoint and inspect the objects while running?

Comment: Nothing. Nothing shows up when I tried to print the objects. Inspecting them only display the address in the form of 0xSOMETHING.

Comment: @Anh stupid question, but have you verified that `wrapper` is not nil? Also, I agree with vfn about setting break points...

Comment: You should accept JRG's answer.  The values are initially set to @"" and not nil.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your assumption is wrong- on creation, the "kSecAttrAccount" and "kSecValueData" are NOT set to nil. They are set to an empty string (that is, ""). So, this code will return true:

```
[username isEqualToString:@""]    // returns true on creation
```

Comment: Instead of doing a direct string comparison, checking for length works just as well. `[username length] > 0`

Answer (score 8):

```
KeychainItemWrapper *wrapper = [[KeychainItemWrapper alloc] initWithIdentifier:@"Test" accessGroup:nil];
NSString *username = [wrapper objectForKey:(id)kSecAttrAccount];
NSString *password = [wrapper objectForKey:(id)kSecValueData];

// initially all these are empty
NSLog(@"username - %@", username); // username - 
NSLog(@"password - %@", password); // password - 

//if empty set your credentials
if ( [username isEqualToString:@""] ) {
    [wrapper setObject:@"your username here" forKey:(id)kSecAttrAccount];
}
if ( [password isEqualToString:@""] ) {
    [wrapper setObject:@"your password here" forKey:(id)kSecValueData];
}

//get the latest credentials - now you have the set values
username = [wrapper objectForKey:(id)kSecAttrAccount];
password = [wrapper objectForKey:(id)kSecValueData];

NSLog(@"username - %@", username); // username - your username here
NSLog(@"password - %@", password); // password - your password here

// reset your keychain items - if  needed
[wrapper resetKeychainItem];
[wrapper release];
```

Comment: The part I'm not sure about is "initially all these are empty". As mentioned in my question, I couldn't get `NSLog` to print any of these values. I'm trying to bring up the login dialog if they're empty/nil, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Will these values keep when relaunching the app?

Answer (score 1):

Same error for me, i checked the return value for `writeToKeychain` function in `KeychainItemWrapper.m` file. Return value is equal to `errSecDuplicateItem`. I don't know why but seems like `SecItemCopyMatching` function does not working properly. (For my other project working properly).

I changed codes for now and working for me:
Updated codes for `writeToKeychain` in `KeychainItemWrapper.m` file:

```
- (void)writeToKeychain
{
    NSDictionary *attributes = NULL;
    NSMutableDictionary *updateItem = NULL;
    OSStatus result;



    if (SecItemCopyMatching((CFDictionaryRef)genericPasswordQuery, (CFTypeRef *)&attributes) == noErr)
    {
        // First we need the attributes from the Keychain.
        updateItem = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:attributes];
        // Second we need to add the appropriate search key/values.
        [updateItem setObject:[genericPasswordQuery objectForKey:(id)kSecClass] forKey:(id)kSecClass];

        // Lastly, we need to set up the updated attribute list being careful to remove the class.
        NSMutableDictionary *tempCheck = [self dictionaryToSecItemFormat:keychainItemData];
        [tempCheck removeObjectForKey:(id)kSecClass];

#if TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR
        // Remove the access group if running on the iPhone simulator.
        // 
        // Apps that are built for the simulator aren't signed, so there's no keychain access group
        // for the simulator to check. This means that all apps can see all keychain items when run
        // on the simulator.
        //
        // If a SecItem contains an access group attribute, SecItemAdd and SecItemUpdate on the
        // simulator will return -25243 (errSecNoAccessForItem).
        //
        // The access group attribute will be included in items returned by SecItemCopyMatching,
        // which is why we need to remove it before updating the item.
        [tempCheck removeObjectForKey:(id)kSecAttrAccessGroup];
#endif

        // An implicit assumption is that you can only update a single item at a time.

        result = SecItemUpdate((CFDictionaryRef)updateItem, (CFDictionaryRef)tempCheck);
        NSAssert( result == noErr, @"Couldn't update the Keychain Item." );
    }
    else
    {
        // No previous item found; add the new one.

        result =  SecItemAdd((CFDictionaryRef)[self dictionaryToSecItemFormat:keychainItemData], NULL);
        NSLog(@"%@",keychainItemData);
        NSLog(@"res : %ld",result);
        if(result == (OSStatus)errSecDuplicateItem)
        {
            NSLog(@"updttttt");
            // First we need the attributes from the Keychain.
            updateItem = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:attributes];
            // Second we need to add the appropriate search key/values.
            [updateItem setObject:[genericPasswordQuery objectForKey:(id)kSecClass] forKey:(id)kSecClass];

            // Lastly, we need to set up the updated attribute list being careful to remove the class.
            NSMutableDictionary *tempCheck = [self dictionaryToSecItemFormat:keychainItemData];
            [tempCheck removeObjectForKey:(id)kSecClass];

#if TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR
            // Remove the access group if running on the iPhone simulator.
            // 
            // Apps that are built for the simulator aren't signed, so there's no keychain access group
            // for the simulator to check. This means that all apps can see all keychain items when run
            // on the simulator.
            //
            // If a SecItem contains an access group attribute, SecItemAdd and SecItemUpdate on the
            // simulator will return -25243 (errSecNoAccessForItem).
            //
            // The access group attribute will be included in items returned by SecItemCopyMatching,
            // which is why we need to remove it before updating the item.
            [tempCheck removeObjectForKey:(id)kSecAttrAccessGroup];
#endif

            // An implicit assumption is that you can only update a single item at a time.

            result = SecItemUpdate((CFDictionaryRef)updateItem, (CFDictionaryRef)tempCheck);
            NSAssert( result == noErr, @"Couldn't update the Keychain Item." );
            return;
        }//if(result == errSecDuplicateItem)*
        NSAssert( result == noErr, @"Couldn't add the Keychain Item." );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the values are initially nil, using

```
if ( [username isEqualToString:@""] )
```

will evaluate to FALSE. You could use

```
if (!username)
```

instead