# Writing to iPhone keychaing using apple KeyChainItemWrapper

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, iphone-sdk-3.0, ios4, keychain

I used KeyChainItemWrapper class form apple to write to the iPhone key chain. In the first occurrence I was able to write to key chain using an identifier. The retrieval also works perfectly. However I changed this identifier and from 2nd time onwards that iPhone key chain wont allow me to write any value to kSecValueData using a different identifier. However in the first time itself it works but not with different identifiers after that. What can be the issue here?

Thank you

Comment: Please share code that illustrates the issue. It is difficult to tell what might be the problem from your description. I've used this wrapper class and it has been reliable.

Comment: Figured it out. I have only used the kSecValueData. When I use this together with kSecAttrAccount this solved the problem. Thank you for your reply

Comment: possible duplicate of [Problem using KeychainItemWrapper](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3595650/problem-using-keychainitemwrapper)